# How to extract numbers from a string in Lua?

Tags: regex, lua

I can't find how to do a simple regex in Lua. In every normal language it is:

```
string:match( "($1,000)", "[\d]+")
```

It returns: 1000 (if you concatenate matches).

I thought `string.match( "($1,000)", "%d+") )` will do the job but it returns nil or 1.

I don't understand it.

Comment: I think I've managed it in a loop: `for m in string.gmatch( value, "%d" ) do print(m) end`

Comment: Comma `,` never match `\d` in any normal language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may remove all matches that follow the `%D+` (1 or more non-digit chars) pattern with `string.gsub`:

```
s = "($1,000)"
res, _ = s:gsub("%D+", "")
print(res)
-- => 1000
```

See the [Lua demo](https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo)